# Rails: ArgumentError in UsersController#create wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I generated scaffold `User` with attributes `name:string` and `email:string`. After fulfilling the form in the browser and hitting `Create User`, following error occurs:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3z6H.png)

Any clue about what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when using an older version of [turbolinks gem](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks). 
Try updating the gem to the latest version.

Add the following to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 2.5.3'
```

Then, do:

```
bundle install
```

Then, restart the rails server and try again!